# Bootstrap popover click event not working properly with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t3muhec8/3/)

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="dbApp" ng-controller="GetEntries" id="myControl">
<div class="box-container" id="box-holder">
    <div class="box-row" id="boxRow">
        <div class="box" ng-repeat="row in entries">
            <div class="box-outer">
                <div class="box-inner"> <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" rel="popover" title="{{ row.model }}" class="item-popover" id="{{ row.Model }}"> <h6>{{ row.Model }}</h6>
                        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/X5TAOCo.png" alt="You should see something here." class="popover-img" /></a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
    var myApp = angular.module('dbApp', []);

myApp.controller('GetEntries', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    console.log("Initiating the controller");
    // $http.get(php page).success(function (data) {
    var data = [{
        "Brand": "Remington",
        "Model": "MK-124",
        "Condition": "NEW"
    }, {
        "Brand": "Blake",
        "Model": "BLA-01",
        "Condition": "NEW"
    }, {
        "Brand": "Winchester",
        "Model": "KRO-17",
        "Condition": "NEW"
    }];
    $scope.entries = data;
    console.log($scope.entries);
}]);

$('.item-popover').click(function () {
    alert('it works!');
});

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    // Section A
    $('body').on('click', '[rel="popover"]', function (e) {
        var i = $(this);
        console.log(i);
        $(this).popover({
            html: true,
            trigger: 'click',
            placement: 'right',
            content: "<div>{{ row.Brand }} {{ row.Model }} {{ row.Condition }}</div>"
        }).popover('toggle');
    });
});

/*  I have also tried this(below) and it works, but only when the function is called from Chrome console.  It does properly populate the popover.

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    //Section B
    $('.item-popover').click(function () {
        $(this).popover({
            html: true,
            trigger: 'manual',
            placement: 'right',
            content: "<div>{{ row.Brand }} {{ row.Model }}{{ row.Condition }}</div>"
        }).popover('toggle');
    });

    $('.item-popover').click(function () {
        alert('it works!');
    });

});
*/
```

So the process so far, (local)phpmyadminDB>SQL>PHP>AngularJS import>Bootstrap popover(with some jquery references).

Firstly, I simplified the DB array for JSfiddle and since it is a local server(XAMPP) I just included it and commented out the actual `$http` request.  Also the `<img>` tag does have `ng-src` but that wouldn't work with JSfiddle.

I know this is probably crazy to include so many frameworks, but **I couldn't find** the appropriate methods or functionality in one place to do cleanly and concisely what I thought should work.

The problem is that no matter how I arrange/code the popover it never seems to 'capture' a click.  Even with the `.on();` method, it will open, but it won't process the `ng-repeat` from AngularJS.  I can toggle the popover from the Chrome console, but that isn't ideal for users.

[This is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JHqN.png) when I call `$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('show');` so I know it is processing the `ng-repeat` properly with `// Section B` (commented in the code).

Comment: One problem is that you didn't form the a tag correctly. It's missing a `>` :  `<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" rel="popover" title="{{ row.model }}" class="item-popover" id="{{ row.Model }}"> <h6>{{ row.Model }}</h6>`

Comment: @stephen.vakil I fixed it on JSfiddle and updated link in post.

Comment: In your JS Fiddle you forgot to add JQuery and then turn on Bootstrap within its options. Once I did that your message "it works" appears when its clicked. http://jsfiddle.net/t3muhec8/4/

Comment: @crazymatt The alert works, and I had that all linked under "External Resources".  The problem is that the popover doesn't work and in HTML has the correct information, but the other way shows the popover but doesn't have the correct information.